# Stored procedure not working in VB6

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vb6, timeout

I have a stored procedure that is called very often as it is used to retrieve an account statement.  The actual stored procedure takes around 10ms in a query window in MSSMS,  and works generally well, but SOMETIMES decides to time out (timeout set to 120 sec) in my VB6 application.  The SP joins tables in between 2 databases, one containing the current transactions (DB #1) and the other containing archived transactions (DB #2).  Using 'sp_who2', no SPID seems to be hogging or blocking the system.

This is the SQL variable I set:

```
DECLARE @rtnRecs int;
strSQL = "EXEC spA_StatementData 
        @sAccountNr = '123abc', 
        @bIncludeHistory = 1, 
        @bShowAllTransactions = 1, 
        @iValidRecords = @rtnRecs OUTPUT"
```

The method I use in VB6 is:

```
rs.Open sql, con, adOpenStatic
```

where rs is the ADODB.Recordset and con is a connection to the database.

This code works well for a long while, say 2 months, and is used by several operators.  It then suddenly, for no apparent reason, stops working - but still works fine in MSSMS.
I am emphasizing VB6 as that's where the problem first appeared, but the same thing is happening in my VB.net code.

One thing of note is that the '@bIncludeHistory' parameter is the condition that sets the JOIN to the archive database (DB #2).  When '@bIncludeHistory' is set to 0, no timeout occurs.

Resetting the service does the trick, but only as a last resort.
Is there anything else I can try?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Beware of parameter sniffing in your stored proc. Try this

```
CREATE PROC spA_StatementData (
        @sAccountNr             VARCHAR(1000)
        , @bIncludeHistory      BIT
        , ...
) AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @_sAccountNr            VARCHAR(1000)
        , @_bIncludeHistory     BIT
        , ...

--- prevent parameter sniffing
SELECT  @_sAccountNr = @sAccountNr
        , @_bIncludeHistory = @bIncludeHistory
        , ...

--- use local @_sAccountNr, @_bIncludeHistory, etc. instead of parmeter variables
```

Comment: Excuse the delay in answering.

Comment: The problem is not the stored procedure as such. The method in VB.Net is different like so: cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("spA_StatementData", rConn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sAccountNr", AcNr)...
...cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
adapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dsStatement As DataSet = New DataSet(cmd.CommandText)
cmd.CommandTimeout = 30
adapter.Fill(dsStatement)
...and still produces the same time out. I wonder if there's anything I can actually check in the database. Like I said, restarting the service does the trick.

Comment: Modify stored proc to prevent param sniffing, don't change anything in the caller code and check if problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me, I missed the following code in the STORE PROCEDURE

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Hope this helps.
Make sure your SP have this code.